# Changing PDF version in Mathematica 10

Tags: pdf-format

With `Export`, I am generating pdf files with pdf version 1.5. Is there a way to generate them with pdf version 1.4 instead?

Comment: There is a file `"\SystemFiles\Converters\Binaries\Windows-x86-64\PDF.exe"` that be used from PDF creation.  *Possibly* replacing this file with one from an older installation may work.  Remember to make back-ups if you try this!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the only documented  options to [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) [`pdf`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/PDF.html) files are *"ImageSize"*, *"ImageResolution"* and *"AllowRasterization"*, so my answer would be no, natively.
[image: Mathematica graphics]

You could down-convert the Mathematica pdf file using Ghostscript (I haven't tried that myself)

```
Run["gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf"]
```

There is currently an open case "CASE:1570212" about metadata in `pdf` export, and I hope they will work on other `Export` options too. You could write to support@wolfram.com requesting that feature.

Comment: Your linux command works. It is a tremendous help. Thanks.

Comment: @rhermans Your gs command created huge files for me (pdf 1.5 was at 75K, pdf1.4 after conversion was at 1.9M). Luckily, I didn't use any features new to Mathematica 10, so I could just recreate the plots in Mathematica 9, which exports to pdf 1.4. Is it possible to alter the gs command such that the size of the file stays small?

Comment: @Neuneck, no idea, I copied theis from old notes without much context.